# Elementary number theory proof involving multiplied gcd's

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble proving the following if and only if statement:

For all integers $a,b,n$, prove that $n|gcd(a,n)gcd(b,n)$ if and only if $n|ab$

For proving $n|gcd(a,n)gcd(b,n)\implies n|ab$, I tried using Bezout's Lemma for both $gcd$s and expanding but didn't know how to show that $n$ divided $ab$.

Also didn't didn't how to approach the converse. Any help?

Comment: $\implies $ is trivial.  $\gcd(a,n)|a$ adn $\gcd(b,n)|b$ and $\gcd(a,n)\gcd(b,n)|ab$ so $n|\gcd(a,n)\gcd(b,n)$ and $\gcd(a,n)\gcd(b,n)|ab$ implies $n|ab.

Answer (score 2):

$c := (a,n)(b,n) = ((a,n)b,(a,n)n) = (ab,nb,na,nn)$

This implies that $\ n\mid c\iff n\mid ab,nb,na,nn\iff n\mid ab$

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a different line of thought, which shows **the claim of the problem to be valid not only for integers but for any elements in an arbitrary unique factorisation domain.**

We concentrate on the reverse implication, as @fleablood has cleared the direct one out of the way for us. First, the general case of integers can be **easily reduced to natural numbers** by taking absolute values (which preserves divisibility, as it entails multiplication by the invertible $1$ or $-1$). Second, were **any of your three numbers to be null, the claimed equivalence would hold trivially.** We can thus limit our attention to the case when all three numbers are non-zero naturals.

Here we must prepare some tools: write $\mathbb{P}$ for **the set of all (natural non-zero) primes** (from the point of view of abstract commutative ring theory, $-2$ and $0$ are also prime). For arbitrary $p \in \mathbb{P}$  **define the $p$-valuation map:**

$$v_{p}: \mathbb{N}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, v_{p}(n)=\mathrm{max}\{k \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ p^k|n \}$$

This map assigns to any number $n$ the exponent with which $p$ appears in the prime factor decomposition of $n$, and it is easy to see that **it is a morphism of monoids between $(\mathbb{N}^{*}, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, +)$.**

For arbitrary set $I$, denote by $\mathbb{N}^{I}$ **the set of all families of naturals indexed by $I$** ; it comes **equipped with a natural addition (carried out component-wise**, the direct product of the standard addition on the individual factors) **rendering it into a cancellable commutative monoid** (cancellability means that every element is cancellable, i.e. it can be cancelled from equations). For arbitrary $\nu \in \mathbb{N}^{I}$ **introduce the support** as:

$$\mathrm{Supp}\ \nu=\{i \in I \ | \ \nu_{i} \neq 0\}$$

The support encodes the indices at which the respective family exhibits non-zero component. Finally **consider the subset**:

$$\mathbb{N}^{(I)}=\{\nu \in \mathbb{N}^{I} \ | \ |\mathrm{Supp}\ \nu| \in \mathbb{N} \ \}$$

**of families of finite support** ($|M|$ denotes the cardinality of set $M$ and claiming that it is a natural number is equivalent to claiming that $M$ is finite, in the formulation of Set Theory that I espouse); this subset is a submonoid of $\mathbb{N}^{I}$.

We also must make use of **the orders that naturally arise**. On the direct product set $\mathbb{N}^{I}$ we are going to consider the order relation $\Pi'$, defined such that:

$$\lambda \leqslant_{\Pi'} \mu \iff (\forall i)(i \in I \implies \lambda_{i} \leqslant \mu_{i})$$

in other words **two families are comparable if and only if their components are comparable** in the standard order on naturals **at every index**. This is none other than **the direct product order** of the individual standard orders on each of the factors $\mathbb{N}$. As the usual order on $\mathbb{N}$ is total **it turns it into a lattice, meaning that any two elements admit infimum (their minimum) and supremum (their maximum)**. The **direct product of lattices remains a lattice under the direct-product order**: the infimum of any two families is expressed as the family of infima between the respective components at every index and similarly for suprema.

**The set $\mathbb{N}^{(I)}$ of families of finite support is a sublattice** of this lattice structure (meaning that infima and suprema between two families of finite support remain families of finite support, which is easy to see) and **when equipped with the restriction $\Pi$ of the parent-order $\Pi'$ the monoid of families of finite support becomes an ordered monoid**, a so-called lattice ordered monoid. The parent monoid of all families equipped with $\Pi'$ is also an ordered monoid (this simply means that the order is preserved under addition).

Denoting the divisibility relation on $\mathbb{N}^{*}$ with $\Delta$, let us notice that **the structure $(\mathbb{N}^{*}, \cdot, \Delta)$ is also a lattice-ordered monoid** (the infimum/supremum between two elements under divisibility being none other than the greatest common divisor/least common multiple).

Finally we can state:

> **Structure theorem.**  Define 
>   $$\Gamma: \mathbb{N}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{(\mathbb{P})}, \ 
> \Gamma(n)=(v_{p}(n))_{p \in \mathbb{P}}$$
>   Then $\Gamma$ **is an isomorphism of ordered monoids between** $(\mathbb{N}^{*}, \cdot, \Delta)$ and $(\mathbb{N}^{(\mathbb{P})}, +, \Pi)$

($\Pi$ defined precisely as above).

The merit of all this is that under $\Gamma$ the equivalence you seek to prove becomes:

> $$\lambda \leqslant_{\Pi} (\lambda \wedge \mu)+(\lambda \wedge \nu) \iff \lambda \leqslant_{\Pi} \mu + \nu$$

Broken down component-wise, this becomes:

> $$m \leqslant \mathrm{min}\{m, n\}+\mathrm{min}\{m, p\} \iff m \leqslant n+p$$

for any $m, n, p \in \mathbb{N}$.

Can you see why this would be so?

There is an even more general argument that can be made. Consider a **commutative cancellable monoid $(M, \cdot)$ with trivial group of units**, equip it with the **relation of divisibility $\Delta$ which thus becomes an order** on $M$ and **assume that $(M, \Delta)$ is an inf-lattice, meaning that any two elements have a greatest common divisor** (so-called GCD monoids). In this setting it holds that

> $$x|(x,y)(x,z) \iff x|yz$$

for any $x,y,z \in M$. Again, we focus on the not so simple implication. Write $$u=(x,y), v=(x,z), x=us=vt, y=uy', z=vz'$$

where it follows from standard properties of GCD-monoids that $(s, y')=(t, z')=1_{M}$. We exploit the relation $x|yz$ in two ways: on the one hand, from $us|uy'z$ and cancellability we infer $s|y'z$ and since $s, y'$ are coprime we obtain $s|z$ ; similarly, on the other hand we have $t|y$.
As we clearly have $t|x$, combining with the above entails $t|(x,y)=u$ and hence $(t,u)=t$. We therefore have $(x, uv)=(tv, uv)=(u,t)v=tv=x$, which means that $x|uv$, **Q.E.D**

Bill Dubuque has expressed this very elegantly!

Comment: Yikes!  I fell asleep at the switch.

Comment: Errare humanum est, happens to us all.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=\gcd(a,n)$ and $e=\gcd(b,n)$ and let $a = da'; b = eb'$ and $n = n'd; n =\overline ne$.  Note: $n'$ is relatively prime to $a'$ and $\overline n$ to $b'$

If $n|de$ then $n|de*a'b' = (da')(eb') = ab$.

That was the simple direction.

If $n|ab$ then $n'd|a'db$ so $n'|a'b$ but as $n'$ and $a'$ are relatively prime $n'|b$.  So $n'$ is a common factor of $b$ and $n$ so $n'$ divides that greatest common factor of $b$ and $n$.  So $n'|e$.

So $n'|e$ so $n'd|de$ so $n|de$.

Likewise we can argue:

If $n|ab$ then $\overline ne|ab'e$ so $\overline n|ab'$ but as $\overline n$ and $a$ are relatively prime $\overline n|a$.  So $\overline n$ is a common factor of $a$ and $n$ so $\overline n$ divides that greatest common factor of $a$ and $n$.  So $\overline n|d$.

So $\overline n|d$ so $\overline ne|de$ so $n|de$.

Comment: Contra the first paragraph in ΑΘΩ's answer.

Comment: Gadzooks!  I was asleep at the swithch!  I meant $\frac nd$ is relative prime to $a'$ and so on.

Comment: First paragraph that by now is already retracted!